# When opening lid, cursor stays in external display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

So I have been using an external display for a long period of time for MacBook Air, sometimes when I open the MacBook Air M1 lid, everything goes from the external display except wall paper and date and so on as normal, though the cursor stays, closing the lid and opening again makes it that I can fully move to Mac, what's going on?